# docker confusion between internal and external users

Tags: docker

so - I'm building a docker container using apache2 on the inside - but I'm having issues with permissions and I don't know how to solve it...

If I run the container with no --user specifications, it runs fine - but I want to *externally* be able to assign it to a user and limit that user to only reading and writing to a particular directory (the one I map in with -v).

However when I run the docker container with --user to that user, the external permissions seem all correct - but internally - apache2 then goes bang saying it can't bind to port 80 - and other things fail writing to code internally.

How do I map users - like mapping ports or volumes.   What I want to achieve is that the container externally only has the permissions of user X in the outer system - but internally it's root, running as the root user id and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to achieve `externally only has the permissions of user X in the outer system - but internally it's root` is the use of `sudo`.

Create an 'internal' user which the UID should be same as the 'external' user:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache apache2 sudo \
  && adduser -S newuser -s /bin/ash -D -H -u 1000 \
  && echo "newuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/newuser \
  && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/newuser
USER newuser
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/ash","-c","sudo httpd -DFOREGROUND"]
```

Example on the host an there's a directory dedicated to a user:

```
drwx------ 2 ec2-user ec2-user 24 Aug 29 11:53 html
```

The directory can be mount as usual:

```
docker built -t myapache2 .
docker run -it -v ${PWD}/html:/html -p 8080:80 myapache2

docker exec -t 31c6cc627813 ls -l /html
total 4
-rwx------    1 ec2-user 1000            58 Aug 29 03:53 index.html

curl localhost:8080
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

Alpine is used here but you can of course use any distro that suits your need.

NOTE: httpd site & folder permission is another topic and is not cover here.

Comment: `newuser` has unrestricted root-equivalent permissions (within the container), so long as it prefixes every command with `sudo`.  From a security perspective this isn't different from just running as root, and indeed in this case the Apache process _does_ run as root with full permissions.

Comment: thanks - this sounds like what I want - will give it a go