# Docker volume change owner to non-root

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I want to create an `uploads` volume and set its owner to the `node` user. But upon running the container I find that the volume's owner is `root`. This is my Docker file:

```
FROM node:12.21
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl vim bash nano

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .

RUN mkdir ./uploads

RUN chown -R node:node .
USER node

RUN yarn install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

VOLUME /home/node/app/uploads
```

I use `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up` to build and run; my `docker-compose.yml` also contains a volume instruction:

```
services:
  ...
  server:
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/home/node/app/uploads
```

My tests show that this instruction in `docker-compose.yml` is what's causing the problem -- without it the `uploads` directory owner is correctly set to `node` -- but I don't understand why. Is the instruction in `docker-compose.yml` redundant in this case? How about if I wanted to map the volume to a local directory (for which I believe this instruction would be necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

Bind volume will retain the origin ownership on the host. You can either change mode the directory on the host to 77x, or you can try this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68969486/docker-confusion-between-internal-and-external-users).

Update: Base on your feedback, you can add the `chmod` in your docker startup script.

Comment: After the container is created I can manually go inside the container as root, and `chown` the volume, setting the owner to `node` (this is a permanent fix). Given that it's possible to set the correct owner, I'd hope there would be some automated way this could be achieved using the Dockerfile and/or docker-compose.yml.  Changing access mode to 77x or conducting all access via `sudo` seem like actions of last resort.