# Is it possible to have a mount and volume in the same container using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Is it possible to have a mount and a volume in the same container? I have been trying to setup a mount and a volume using different paths but I am having trouble with getting the correct permission sets.

My docker file:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
RUN apk add dumb-init

RUN addgroup appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup

RUN mkdir -p /app/logs

WORKDIR /app/


COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install


COPY . /app
RUN chown -R appuser:appgroup /app/

USER appuser
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  my-service:
    user: "1000"
    container_name: demou 
    build:
      context: . 
    image: "my-service" 

    working_dir: /app/ 

    ports:
      - 80:80 
    environment:
      - NODE_VERSION=16 
    volumes:
       - ~/logs:/app/logs/:rw
       - other:/app/other/:rw
    command: sh -c "dumb-init node src/server.js"

    networks:
      - Snet
volumes:
  other:
    name: "other"
networks:
  Snet:
    name: "Snetwork"
```

If I keep `user: "1000"` in the docker-compose file, the mount works and I can see the files but the volume fails and I get permission denied when attempting to write to app/other as specified in the volume declaration.
Removing `user: "1000"` resolves the volume permission but causes the mount to fail with permission denied.

using docker exec, I can see the following permissions with the `user: "1000"`

```
drwxr-xr-x    1 appuser  appgroup      4096 Nov 15 15:08 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Nov 15 15:08 ..
drwxrwxr-x    2 node     node          4096 Nov 15 15:08 logs
drwxr-xr-x    1 appuser  appgroup      4096 Nov 15 15:08 node_modules
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Nov 15 15:08 other
-rw-rw-r--    1 appuser  appgroup     31394 Nov 15 11:55 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--    1 appuser  appgroup       274 Nov 15 11:55 package.json
drwxrwxr-x    1 appuser  appgroup      4096 Nov 13 13:56 src
```

Also, why is logs directory owned by node:node? I haven't setup any node user or group.

My OS/docker host details:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/logs:/app/logs/:rw`

The directory `~/logs` must be granted rw to 1000:1000 (appuser:appgroup) because this is an existing directory on the host.

`other:/app/other/:rw`

Named volume is created by docker on the host which is owned by `root` (except rootless mode). Use `VOLUME` to retain the permission set in Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
RUN apk add dumb-init
RUN addgroup appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup
RUN mkdir -p /app/logs && mkdir /app/other
WORKDIR /app/
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN chown -R appuser:appgroup /app/
USER appuser
VOLUME /app/other
```

`why is logs directory owned by node:node?`

This user:group was created in the base image node:16-alpine.

Alternate [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68969486/docker-confusion-between-internal-and-external-users) that solve similar issue, if it suits your need.

Comment: My apologies for the delayed response. I had a personal matter to deal with. If I change the user to user: "0", I get both mount and volume to work. would that be considered a bad practice to use "0" as in root?

Comment: after chmod 755 logs, writing files from the containers still throws an permission denied

Comment: typo, let me retype. ~/logs this is a directory in the user home directory, normally it is the same user that runs the container. If you can chmod **666** this directory you can bind mount without the need to run as root. You can also create a named volume for this directory just like you did for "other". When you want to examine the log volume, just run a simple busybox and mount it like docker run -it -v log:/log busybox ash. If you can run as non-root - that's good. If you cannot, it is not a bad practice (otherwise why it exists in the first place?) but something you need to be mindful of.